# Listening UDP and monitoring

Tags: c++, udp

I have already created a UDP socket (UDP has been bound) and now i wanted the server to listen and if any client tries to connect, the listening UDP will then accept and pass the socket to a new thread to perform recvfrom and sento operation.

So how am I going to do that? How the client tells the server that he wanted to connect? May I use `FD_CONNECT` and `FD_ACCEPT` in UDP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP is a connectionless protocol. You don't need to connect an udp socket. Pay attention that use a connect on an UDP socket may have a different semantic respect what you are expecting: on linux for example a connect invoked on a UDP socket , "bind" that socket to a specific IP address, but this is only a local binding, nothing happens over the network.

Comment: So how am I need to know the client wants to connect with the server? And what is the FD Event for that?

Comment: @Chicko Bueno : there is no connection in UDP. You just receive or send datagrams. This is because UDP needs no handshake to establish connection parameters. It's faster but less reliable than TCP. When you receive a UDP datagram you can read it with a classic recv like you would have done with TCP.

Comment: @Overbose Thanks for your feedback. If I would like to know the existence of a client, I just need my UDP to wait until a client sending some data and the event correspond to that is `FD_READ`. Am I correct?